# How do you update the nodes and connectors of a SyncFusion UWP Diagram programmatically?

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I'm evaluating the SyncFusion SfDiagram and am having trouble finding a way to update the nodes and connectors from my C# in UWP?  I'm testing against their sample given in the [Getting Started](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdiagram/getting-started) documentation and modified the EmpId to be a string.  The result is that the new node is added but the original nodes still are displayed.  I would expect to only see the two nodes that I add in the C# code.

I'm finding their documentation a bit confusing.  I've tried the following:

XAML

```
<local:Employees  x:Name="EmployeesCollection" x:Key="Employees">
    <local:Employee Name="Elizabeth" EmpId="1" ParentId="" Designation="CEO"/>
    <local:Employee Name="Christina" EmpId="2" ParentId="1" Designation="Manager"/>
</local:Employees>
```

C#

```
EmployeesCollection.Clear();
employee e = new Employee();
e.Name = t.Designation = e.EmpId = "10";
e.ParentId = "";
EmployeesCollection.Add(e);

employee e = new Employee();
e.Name = t.Designation = e.EmpId = "11";
e.ParentId = "10";
EmployeesCollection.Add(e);

diagram.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting next time

Comment: You could add a breakpoint at `EmployeesCollection.Clear();` to check if there is anything in the collection before you're clearing it. If its empty (as I suspect), try to find another way to access & clear the Items or Itemssource of `Employees` or `EmployeesCollection`.

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting.  I haven't posted here often and played with it a bit.  CTRL+K didn't clean it up.  I'll work on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the datasource settings as follows at run time,

```
 Employees employees = new Employees(); 
    DataSourceSettings settings = new DataSourceSettings(); 
    settings.ParentId = "ParentId"; 
    settings.Id = "EmpId"; 


    employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpId = 1, ParentId = "", Name = "Charly", Designation = "Manager" }); 
    employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpId = 2, ParentId = "1", Name = "Ronald", Designation = "TeamLead" }); 

    settings.DataSource = employees; 
    sfdiagram.DataSourceSettings = settings;
```

The RefreshFrequency property support for LayoutManager. The RefreshFrequency property is used to update the Layout whenever the Nodes or Connectors collection is Changed. The provided code example to represent this. Please refer to the code example as below.

**Code example:**

```
sfdiagram.LayoutManager.RefreshFrequency = RefreshFrequency.ArrangeParsing;

Here, sfdiagram is instance of SfDiagram
```

For more information, please refer to the knowledge base link as below.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6258/how-to-update-layout-automatically-when-collection-is-changed

Suggestion 2: 
The UpdateLayout method support for Layout. It is used to arrange the Node Position.The provided the code example to represent this.

**Code Example:**

```
//Diagram Loaded Event 
sfdiagram.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded; 
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
sfdiagram.LayoutManager.Layout.UpdateLayout(); 
} 

Here, sfdiagram is instance of SfDiagram.
```

For more information about UpdateLayout, please refer the documentation link as below.

Documentation link: https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdiagram/automatic-layouts#updating-the-layout

Regards,

Keerthivasan R.

Comment: Thank you for your post.  Originally, I was attempting to clear the named collection (Employees) that I had created in the sample.  Rather than nulling out the DataSourceSettings as I had been, I am now recreating a new collection of employees and assigning it to the diagram DataSourceSettings as you have in your code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am evaluating the SF Diagram as well.

I am trying to do everything from a ViewModel perspective.  I have the diagram's DataSourceSetting bound to a VM property of type DataSourceSettings.
From the ViewModel I change the DataSourceSettings Datasource property to the new collection.

```
 Activities = new ObservableCollection<Activity>(App.AppState.BPAnalysis.IDEFOActivities[0].Activities.ToList());

        DS.DataSource = Activities;

        OnDiagramUpdated(EventArgs.Empty);
```

Now comes the ugly part from a ViewModel perspective.  My Viewmodel raises a "OnDiagramUpdated" event and I handle itin te codebhind like this:

```
 public sealed partial class Diagramer : UserControl
{

    ViewModels.DiagramVM vm = null;
    public Diagramer()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModels.DiagramVM();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        vm.DiagramUpdated += (s, e) =>
        {                
            DG1.LayoutManager.RefreshFrequency = RefreshFrequency.ArrangeParsing;
        };

    }

}
```

The RefreshFrequency line causes the redraw.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim.  I am now using the approach to set the RefreshFrequency to get the nodes to auto-format.  It cleans things up but now I can't drag and drop the nodes.  Seems like they are locked whever they are placed.  Do you know if I need to suppress a "OnChanged" type of event to permit a user's node arrangement?

Comment: I have been able to move things around, though I have not attempted to do any drag and drop[ yet.  My requirements will not, at present anyway, require drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, Keyur Patel.  I found that I have to null out the DataSourceSettings before updating (strange).  I added x:Name to the DataSourceSettings from their sample (naming it DiagramDataSourceSettings).  Here's what I added to get it to clear the original nodes and update with my new nodes:

```
diagram.DataSourceSettings = null;
diagram.DataSourceSettings = DiagramDataSourceSettings;
diagram.UpdateLayout();
```

The issue now is that when it updates it places the new nodes in the upper right corner (slightly out of view).

Comment: Keyur - I also set a breakpoint to check the collection upon calling Clear().  It was still populated with my initial nodes.  After clearing, it did actually clear the nodes and I could repopulate.  But without nulling out the DataSourceSettings, the old nodes were still displayed in the Diagram.